# Self-relation in table causes ERROR "...cycles or multiple cascade paths"

Tags: sql-server

I have already read a lot of explanations about "...cycles or multiple paths" error. But it seems to me that I have a bit different problem, I have no cycle or cascade in my constraint, just to set null WHERE id_boss = id_work.

### ONE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Workers](
    [id_work] [int] NOT NULL,
    [id_boss] [int] NULL,
    [money] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Workers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id_work] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

### ONE MORE CONSTRAINT:

```
ALTER TABLE Workers ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Boss FOREIGN KEY (id_boss) 
REFERENCES Workers (id_work) ON DELETE SET NULL
```

### ERROR:

> Msg 1785, Level 16, State 0, Line 5 Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_Boss' on table 'Workers' may cause cycles or multiple cascade
>   paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify
>   other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 5
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Thanks for any help or explanation.
Pavel

Answer (score 0):

Actually you cannot add foreign key that linked to the same table. 
That's why it called **foreign** key - it should be linked to other table.

more detail you can read here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464(v=sql.105).aspx